# Compile-Time Topological Sort Exceeds Recursion Depth in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, templates, template-meta-programming

#### Hello :)

I'm implementing a compile-time topological sort algorithm using C++ template metaprogramming. The algorithm is designed to sort a graph of dependencies between different systems in a game engine, but it could be used to sort any directed acyclic graph (DAG).

The graph is represented as a tuple of SystemNode objects, each of which represents a system and its dependencies. The algorithm sorts these nodes in a way that each node appears before its dependencies in the sorted list.

### Breakdown

1. **GraphWithDegrees_t**: This is the starting point of the algorithm. It takes a tuple of `SystemNode` objects and converts each node into a `NodeWithDegree` object, which is a node that also includes its degree (the number of nodes that depend on it). The degree of each node is calculated by the `CountDependencies` struct.
2. **TopologicalSort**: This is the main part of the algorithm. It's a recursive struct that performs the topological sort. It works as follows:

   - Extracts all nodes with a degree of zero (i.e., nodes that no other nodes depend on). These nodes are added to the `ExtractedSystems` tuple, which holds the sorted nodes.
   - Collects the dependencies of the zero-degree nodes. This is done to know which nodes' degrees need to be decremented in the next step.
   - Removes the zero-degree nodes from the original tuple.
   - Decrements the degree of any nodes that depended on the removed nodes. This is done by checking if a node is in the dependencies collected in the previous step.
   - Recursively calls `TopologicalSort` with the updated tuple and the `ExtractedSystems` tuple.
   - When the tuple is empty (i.e., all nodes have been sorted), the recursion ends and the `ExtractedSystems` tuple is returned as the result.
3. **ExtractZeroDegree_t and RemoveZeroDegree_t**: These structs are used to extract and remove zero-degree nodes from a tuple. They work by recursively iterating over the tuple and adding/removing nodes to/from a new tuple based on their degree.
4. **DecrementDegrees_t**: This struct is used to decrement the degree of nodes that depend on a given set of nodes. It works by recursively iterating over the tuple and decrementing the degree of any nodes that are in the `Dependencies` tuple.
5. **AddSystemsToTuple_t**: This struct is used to add the zero-degree nodes to the `ExtractedSystems` tuple. It works by recursively iterating over the tuple of zero-degree nodes and adding each node to the `ExtractedSystems` tuple.

#### Problem

The problem I'm facing is that the algorithm works fine for up to 15 types, but with 16 types, it exceeds the maximum recursion depth. I believe the recursion depth should be O(M), where M is the maximum degree count, so I'm not sure why it's failing with 16 types.

My questions are:

1. Why does this algorithm exceed the maximum recursion depth with 16
   types?
2. How can I modify it to handle more types?
3. Given the complexity of this approach, would it be advisable to
   adopt a simpler approach to achieve the same result? If so, what
   alternatives could be recommended?

Please take me easy, I'm new here :)

#### Source Code

You can also reproduce the probelm here: https://godbolt.org/z/T8cohdasr.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string_view>

template<typename SystemType, typename... DependencyTypes>
class SystemNode;

template<typename SystemType, typename... DependencyTypes>
class SystemNode<SystemType, std::tuple<DependencyTypes...>>
{
public:
    using system = SystemType;
    using dependencies = std::tuple<DependencyTypes...>;
};

template <typename System, typename Dependencies, size_t Degree>
struct NodeWithDegree 
{
    using system = System;
    using dependencies = Dependencies;
    static constexpr size_t degree = Degree;
};

template <typename Node, size_t Degree>
struct ToNodeWithDegree
{
    using type = NodeWithDegree<typename Node::system, typename Node::dependencies, Degree>;
};

template <typename Node, size_t Degree>
using ToNodeWithDegree_t = typename ToNodeWithDegree<Node, Degree>::type;

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
struct Contains;

template <typename T, typename... Us>
struct Contains<T, std::tuple<Us...>> : std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, Us>...> {};

template <typename T, typename... Us>
constexpr size_t Contains_v = Contains<T, Us...>::value;

template <typename Node, typename Nodes>
struct CountDependencies;

template <typename Node, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct CountDependencies<Node, std::tuple<First, Rest...>>
{
    static constexpr size_t value = 
        Contains_v<typename Node::system, typename First::dependencies> 
        + CountDependencies<Node, std::tuple<Rest...>>::value;
};

template <typename Node>
struct CountDependencies<Node, std::tuple<>>
{
    static constexpr size_t value = 0;
};

template <typename... Nodes>
struct GraphWithDegrees
{
    template<typename Node>
    static constexpr size_t CountDependencies_v = CountDependencies<Node, std::tuple<Nodes...>>::value;

    using type = std::tuple<ToNodeWithDegree_t<Nodes, CountDependencies_v<Nodes>>...>;
};

template <typename... Nodes>
using GraphWithDegrees_t = typename GraphWithDegrees<Nodes...>::type;

template <typename NodesWithDegrees, typename ZeroDegreeNodes = std::tuple<>>
struct ExtractZeroDegree;

template <typename FirstNode, typename... RestNodes, typename... ZeroDegreeNodes>
struct ExtractZeroDegree<std::tuple<FirstNode, RestNodes...>, std::tuple<ZeroDegreeNodes...>>
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<
        FirstNode::degree == 0,
        typename ExtractZeroDegree<std::tuple<RestNodes...>, std::tuple<ZeroDegreeNodes..., FirstNode>>::type,
        typename ExtractZeroDegree<std::tuple<RestNodes...>, std::tuple<ZeroDegreeNodes...>>::type
    >;
};

template <typename... ZeroDegreeNodes>
struct ExtractZeroDegree<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<ZeroDegreeNodes...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<ZeroDegreeNodes...>; 
};

template <typename NodesWithDegrees, typename ZeroDegreeNodes = std::tuple<>>
using ExtractZeroDegree_t = typename ExtractZeroDegree<NodesWithDegrees, ZeroDegreeNodes>::type;

template <typename NodesWithDegrees, typename NonZeroDegreeNodes = std::tuple<>>
struct RemoveZeroDegree;

template <typename FirstNode, typename... RestNodes, typename... NonZeroDegreeNodes>
struct RemoveZeroDegree<std::tuple<FirstNode, RestNodes...>, std::tuple<NonZeroDegreeNodes...>>
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<
        FirstNode::degree == 0,
        typename RemoveZeroDegree<std::tuple<RestNodes...>, std::tuple<NonZeroDegreeNodes...>>::type,
        typename RemoveZeroDegree<std::tuple<RestNodes...>, std::tuple<NonZeroDegreeNodes..., FirstNode>>::type
    >;
};

template <typename... NonZeroDegreeNodes>
struct RemoveZeroDegree<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<NonZeroDegreeNodes...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<NonZeroDegreeNodes...>; 
};

template <typename NodesWithDegrees, typename NonZeroDegreeNodes = std::tuple<>>
using RemoveZeroDegree_t = typename RemoveZeroDegree<NodesWithDegrees, NonZeroDegreeNodes>::type;

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
struct Prepend;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Prepend<T, std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<T, Ts...>;
};

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
using Prepend_t = typename Prepend<T, Tuple>::type;

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
struct AddUnique;

template <typename T>
struct AddUnique<T, std::tuple<>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<T>;
};

template <typename T, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct AddUnique<T, std::tuple<First, Rest...>>
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<
        std::is_same_v<T, First>,
        std::tuple<First, Rest...>,
        Prepend_t<First, typename AddUnique<T, std::tuple<Rest...>>::type>
    >;
};

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
using AddUnique_t = typename AddUnique<T, Tuple>::type;

template <typename Tuple1, typename Tuple2>
struct AddUniqueElements;

template <typename First, typename... Rest, typename Tuple2>
struct AddUniqueElements<std::tuple<First, Rest...>, Tuple2>
{
    using type = typename AddUniqueElements<std::tuple<Rest...>, AddUnique_t<First, Tuple2>>::type;
};

template <typename Tuple2>
struct AddUniqueElements<std::tuple<>, Tuple2>
{
    using type = Tuple2;
};

template <typename Tuple1, typename Tuple2>
using AddUniqueElements_t = typename AddUniqueElements<Tuple1, Tuple2>::type;

template <typename Nodes>
struct CollectDependencies;

template <typename FirstNode, typename... RestNodes>
struct CollectDependencies<std::tuple<FirstNode, RestNodes...>>
{
    using type = AddUniqueElements_t<
        typename FirstNode::dependencies,
        typename CollectDependencies<std::tuple<RestNodes...>>::type
    >;
};

template <>
struct CollectDependencies<std::tuple<>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

template <typename... Nodes>
using CollectDependencies_t = typename CollectDependencies<Nodes...>::type;

template <typename NodesWithDegrees, typename Dependencies>
struct DecrementDegrees;

template <typename FirstNode, typename... RestNodes, typename... Dependencies>
struct DecrementDegrees<std::tuple<FirstNode, RestNodes...>, std::tuple<Dependencies...>>
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<
        Contains_v<typename FirstNode::system, std::tuple<Dependencies...>>,
        Prepend_t<
            NodeWithDegree<
                typename FirstNode::system, 
                typename FirstNode::dependencies, 
                FirstNode::degree - 1
            >, 
            typename DecrementDegrees<std::tuple<RestNodes...>, std::tuple<Dependencies...>>::type
        >,
        Prepend_t<
            FirstNode, 
            typename DecrementDegrees<std::tuple<RestNodes...>, std::tuple<Dependencies...>>::type
        >
    >;
};

template <typename... Dependencies>
struct DecrementDegrees<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<Dependencies...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<>; 
};

template <typename NodesWithDegrees, typename Dependencies>
using DecrementDegrees_t = typename DecrementDegrees<NodesWithDegrees, Dependencies>::type;

template <typename NodesWithDegrees, typename ExtractedSystems>
struct AddSystemsToTuple;

template <typename FirstNode, typename... RestNodes, typename... ExtractedSystems>
struct AddSystemsToTuple<std::tuple<FirstNode, RestNodes...>, std::tuple<ExtractedSystems...>>
{
    using nextTuple = std::tuple<RestNodes...>;
    using newExtractedSystems = std::tuple<typename FirstNode::system, ExtractedSystems...>;
    using type = typename AddSystemsToTuple<nextTuple, newExtractedSystems>::type;
};

template <typename... ExtractedSystems>
struct AddSystemsToTuple<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<ExtractedSystems...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<ExtractedSystems...>;
};

template <typename NodesWithDegrees, typename ExtractedSystems>
using AddSystemsToTuple_t = typename AddSystemsToTuple<NodesWithDegrees, ExtractedSystems>::type;

template <typename SystemsWithDegrees, typename ExtractedSystems = std::tuple<>>
struct TopologicalSort
{
    using ZeroDegreeSystems = ExtractZeroDegree_t<SystemsWithDegrees>;
    using NewExtractedSystems = AddSystemsToTuple_t<ZeroDegreeSystems, ExtractedSystems>;
    using Dependencies = CollectDependencies_t<ZeroDegreeSystems>;
    using RemainingSystems = RemoveZeroDegree_t<SystemsWithDegrees>;
    using DecrementRemainingSystems = DecrementDegrees_t<RemainingSystems, Dependencies>;
    using type = typename TopologicalSort<DecrementRemainingSystems, NewExtractedSystems>::type;
};

template <typename ExtractedSystems>
struct TopologicalSort<std::tuple<>, ExtractedSystems>
{
    using type = ExtractedSystems;
};

template <typename SystemsWithDegrees, typename ExtractedSystems = std::tuple<>>
using TopologicalSort_t = typename TopologicalSort<SystemsWithDegrees, ExtractedSystems>::type;

template <typename T>
constexpr auto type_name() noexcept {
    std::string_view name = "Error: unsupported compiler", prefix, suffix;
#ifdef __clang__
    name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    prefix = "auto type_name() [T = ";
    suffix = "]";
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    prefix = "constexpr auto type_name() [with T = ";
    suffix = "]";
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    name = __FUNCSIG__;
    prefix = "auto __cdecl type_name<";
    suffix = ">(void) noexcept";
#else
    static_assert(false, "Unsupported compiler!");
#endif
    name.remove_prefix(prefix.size());
    name.remove_suffix(suffix.size());
    return name;
}

template <typename T>
void printSystem()
{
    std::cout << type_name<T>() << '\n';
}

struct System1 {};
struct System2 {};
struct System3 {};
struct System4 {};
struct System5 {};
struct System6 {};
struct System7 {};
struct System8 {};
struct System9 {};
struct System10 {};
struct System11 {};
struct System12 {};
struct System13 {};
struct System14 {};
struct System15 {};
struct System16 {};
struct System17 {};
struct System18 {};
struct System19 {};
struct System20 {};

using Node1 = SystemNode<System1, std::tuple<>>;
using Node2 = SystemNode<System2, std::tuple<System1>>;
using Node3 = SystemNode<System3, std::tuple<System2>>;
using Node4 = SystemNode<System4, std::tuple<System3>>;
using Node5 = SystemNode<System5, std::tuple<System4>>;
using Node6 = SystemNode<System6, std::tuple<System5>>;
using Node7 = SystemNode<System7, std::tuple<System6>>;
using Node8 = SystemNode<System8, std::tuple<System7>>;
using Node9 = SystemNode<System9, std::tuple<System8>>;
using Node10 = SystemNode<System10, std::tuple<System9>>;
using Node11 = SystemNode<System11, std::tuple<System10>>;
using Node12 = SystemNode<System12, std::tuple<System11>>;
using Node13 = SystemNode<System13, std::tuple<System12>>;
using Node14 = SystemNode<System14, std::tuple<System13>>;
using Node15 = SystemNode<System15, std::tuple<System14>>;
using Node16 = SystemNode<System16, std::tuple<System15>>;
using Node17 = SystemNode<System17, std::tuple<System16>>;
using Node18 = SystemNode<System18, std::tuple<System17>>;
using Node19 = SystemNode<System19, std::tuple<System18>>;
using Node20 = SystemNode<System20, std::tuple<System19>>;

int main()
{
    using tuple = GraphWithDegrees_t<
        Node10, Node9, Node8, Node7, Node6, Node5, Node4, Node3, Node2, Node1, 
        Node11, Node12, Node13, Node14, Node15, Node16, Node17, Node18, Node19, Node20
    >;
    using SortedTuple = TopologicalSort_t<tuple>;
    printSystem<SortedTuple>();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

````
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc```
````

Comment: I know constexpr has something in the order of 500 depth (on MSVC). I guess there is some similar kind of limit on template recursion.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please don't post working code. Only post **non-working** code.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI if you replace:

using tuple = GraphWithDegrees_t<
        Node10, Node9, Node8, Node7, Node6, Node5, Node4, Node3, Node2, Node1, 
        Node11, Node12, Node13, Node14, Node15, Node16, Node17, Node18, Node19, Node20
    >;

It doesn't work for me: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc

Comment: Please do not post code that needs to be modified in order to reproduce the problem. Post code that reproduces the problem as is, with zero modifications.

Comment: Okay, Ill edit the question to be more clear, sorry for the incovenience

Comment: Anyway, your compiler is simply out of memory. It did not reach any kind of template instantiation depth limit. It just crashed. I verified locally that other compilers can compile this but it takes them too damn long, so godbolt kills them for exceeding its time limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compiler has an internal error/out of memory condition. It is not some kind of arbitrary nested template instantiation limit.

I was able to compile a version with 20 nodes on my machine locally. It took about 20 seconds with gcc and about 30 seconds with clang.

I then increased the number of nodes to 50. The compilation brought my computer (admittedly not very beefy by today's standards) to a crawl and I killed it after 20 minutes or so.

So in practice it's probably not a good idea to push template metaprogramming that far.

Comment: So, you're suggesting that a run-time approach would be better suited? Do you think there is room for optimization -using this approach, to maybe reach 100 nodes in a few seconds?

Comment: The same algorithm usually runs much faster in runtime than in compile-time, if the runtime version is optimized (e.g. `gcc -O2` or `gcc -O3`). It also uses less memory.

Comment: The advantage of computing something in compile-time is that the final result is readily available each time the program is run. That's a net benefit if the program is compiled only a few times, but run many times.

Comment: @bibanac I don't think it makes sense to pursue the TMP route. Templates were never designed to do such things. A consteval function might be a doable alternative.